# Getting Process List on Oracle Solaris 11

Tags: c, gcc, solaris

i used to get a list of processs under linux by enumerating the /proc file system, since it had plain-text files that i can read data from (stat, status, exe link....) but thats not the case on solaris, i tried porting my tools to Oracle Solaris 11 (my first solaris) but it wont work, i tried accessing the /proc folder manually, but couldn't find anything readable, but `ps -fu user` works !

is it possible that someone can point me on how to get a list of processes uneder solaris?
im coding in gcc btw.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get process info programmatically in C/C++ from a Solaris system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445382/how-to-get-process-info-programmatically-in-c-c-from-a-solaris-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Linux, Solaris /proc is providing binary data, not text one.

Solaris has an extensive and detailed manual page [proc(4)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19963-01/821-1473/proc-4/index.html) describing what the different files under a process number hierarchy contain, how to access them and what structures to use in order to get their content.

This manual page is of course also accessible locally with `man -s 4 proc`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this: [How to get process info programmatically in C/C++ from a Solaris system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445382/how-to-get-process-info-programmatically-in-c-c-from-a-solaris-system)

Answer (score 0):

You want the interface described by /usr/include/procfs.h and /usr/include/sys/procfs.h to decode the binary data in /proc